# Data distribution in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column with close to a million rows, with values ranging from 25-140000 (approx.), although not every value in that range is present. How can I get a graph showing the distribution of the values (probably a bell-type graph), preferably only the ones that actually exist?

Answer (score 0):

Enter the pivot table.

highlight data insert pivot table.

Use column lables = data
Use count of data on values
Then create your graph from the pivot table results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a chart that shows the distribution, including gaps for values not present, you'll probably want to use Excel's **Frequency** formula.  This takes two arguments, the data array you're analysing and a bin array (to count the unique instances of those values).  For the bin argument you can use an array of single values (1,2,3...n) or group values (5,10,15...n).  With a range of 25-140,000, bins of a value greater than 1 may be preferable otherwise you'll end up with a chart with 140,000 columns and gaps (or other anomolies) will be hard to see.

Once you have your Frequency array, just chart the values as a column chart and you'll get something that resembles a distribution histogram.

Note:  Frequency is an array formula, so you'll need to select the cell range you want it to fill, and finish it with [Ctrl]-[Shift]-[Enter].

**EDIT:**  Here's a sample chart using the data parameters you mentioned.  It uses random values so the distribution is relatively uniform, but it shows how dense the values would be.[image: Frequency Chart]

It's also worth noting that Excel didn't choke too much on the calcs-I got a slightly delayed refresh on the chart formating, but it handled the amount of data fairly well.